# Taxonomy Filter with parents and child of select parent dropdown`s

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

On my website i have pet type (dog, cat, rabbit...) those are taxonomies, and every pet type has its own child taxonomies called pet breed. So lets say we selected in first dropdown dog, in second dropdown i want to list dog breeds.

I have tried with http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select but i cant make it work.

I tried with Views but still my exposed filters doesnt show at all on Preview or in Block...

Any help would be nice. I tried searching but no luck...

http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/ this is what i want to acomplish same thing as that filter they have but just without taht location field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to check [Simple hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/shs) module, which looks promising to work views exposed filter, if you use the same for the content type. Though I have used hierarchical select for what you are trying to do & by playing sometime you would also be able to achieve what you are looking for. Views has many things & it takes times sometimes to get what we want...
You would like to check [Views Hack](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module for the custom arrangement of block of yours..

Answer (score 0):

the [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module is the correct solution for this purpose, why it does not work with you?

Setup steps:
1- add the module folder to sites/all/module
2- go to modules page and enable hierarchical select
3- add new field (Term reference) into your content type with (Hierarchical Select) widget type.

Comment: Not sure how to set it up, I sure am doing something wrong here...

Comment: Ok can you tell me the steps i need to take when using Hierarchical Select module? I know how to make 1 dropdown but im not sure how to make second ona that will be populated dynamicly with childs depending of first one

Comment: Thanks for this i wil come handy in content type creation, but i want to filter nodes and i think i need to use views for it. 

I actaully need same thing like here http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/ that filter just without location field...